# iOS Chinese String shown ? when in Button Label

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, encoding, character-encoding

Here I have some Strings([String] in swift), I'm not sure whether it is Chinese.
I get it from an internet interface,and made it shown on a Button as it's title,It shown like (the ?)
[image]

I use xcode debuging,it showed(it seems it could recognized by xcode but not my iPhone)  [image]

I couldn't get this orriginal code, but I have a another one with the same problem ""

So the Qusetion is, How could I avoid this happened?
I've tried with encoding recognize to remove those string like `word.canBeConvertedToEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)`

but seems no sense, Any suggestions would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Hi this is common problem because unicode characters are not supported in all fonts.

Symbol: ""

Unicode of the symbol : "U+E815" Base on this [link](http://www.utf8icons.com/character/59413/UTF-8-character).

Fonts that support are : http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/e815/fontsupport.htm

Comment: So I know What's the problem.. Any API or demos I could use to determine whether a string is supported by System Default Font?